# How to get cache size of web application in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

My question is just simple as how to get cache size if web application is developed in `reactjs`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and you'll get help
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the `StorageEstimate`, that you can query like this:

```js
navigator.storage.estimate().then(({quota, usage}) => ...)
```